# How can I exec the ping command in nodejs on lambda?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

This runs locally and returns the ping output:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
function execute(command, callback){
    exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){ callback(stdout); });
}
execute("ping -c 3 localhost", function(name){
  console.log(name);
});
```

Running this in lambda it completes but I never see output:

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    var exec = require('child_process').exec;
    function execute(command, callback){
        exec(command, function(error, stdout, stderr){ callback(stdout); });
    }
    execute("ping -c 3 localhost", function(name){
      console.log(name);
    });
};
```

How do I get it to show output?

Comment: Not sure what is the aim of your question - Is it your use case to get the ping information, or is this a basic question how/where/when you'd see the console output from Lambda?

Comment: Sandeep Patel has already answered the underlying question, though if anyone else wanders here and wants the question answered literally as asked, they might be looking for [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v18.x/api/util.html#utilpromisifyoriginal)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sadly there is no way to do ICMP pings from inside AWS Lambda currently - the main issue is that the container environment that Lambdas run inside lacks the CAP_NET_RAW capability needed to allow an application to use raw sockets.

There's no way around this, even trying to use the command line ping utility inside the Amazon Linux container the Lambda runs inside of won't work.

Source:https://github.com/jethrocarr/lambda-ping.
They also proposed a solution you can try.