# How to add ping module in aws lambda using python

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda

I want to monitor a server using AWS Lambda function with Python 3.9 version.

I'm using ping test connection and here's my code

```
import subprocess
import platform

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    SERVERS = [
        ('203.124.136.164', 'Local Host 1')
    ]

    for (server, name) in SERVERS:
        check_connection(server, name)
            
def check_connection(server, name):
    if ping(server):
        print("%s is UP" % (name))
    else:
        print("%s is DOWN" % (name))

def ping(server):
    try:
        output = subprocess.check_output("ping -{} 1 {}".format('n' if platform.system().lower() == "windows" else 'c', server ), shell=True, universal_newlines=True)
        if 'unreachable' in output:
            print('unreachable')
            return False
        elif 'timed out' in output:
            print('timed out')
            return False
        else:
            print('success')
            return True
    except Exception as err:
        print("An error occurred: %s" % (err.__str__()))
        return False
```

But I got an error:

```
/bin/sh: ping: command not found
An error occurred: Command 'ping -c 1 203.124.136.164' returned non-zero exit status 127.
```

Why I got that error and what is the right implementation to monitor a server using IP?
I'm just a beginner. Please help!

Disclaimer: the IP provided on the code is just dummy.

Answer (score 1):

I think AWS Lambda doesn't allow for ICMP to go outbound. It only allows for TCP or UDP outbound so since ping is neither it doesn't work. Even if you try to make a custom layer and import to Lambda you will get a permissions error since ICMP is not allowed.

Sorry my friend, the easiest work around I believe would to make a T1.micro to run the full python code.

Comment: Do you know of any AWS docs that say lambda doesn't allow ICMP outbound?

Comment: this is a related answer to the same issue: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/59291109/2736289

Answer (score 0):

######### update ############

it seems that lambda functions don't accept to send socket (permissions) maybe you need to use other kind of methods to do that, as someone says: use instance

---

You need put your lambda function behind a nat gateway or nat ec2 instance

Because nat gateway return to lambda function the answer that you do in your ICPM requests, So you need put your lambda function in private subnets with Nat gw or Nat Instance